# I can not control Banshee from the sound menu in Gnome 3 Shell

Tags: 11.10, banshee, gnome, indicator-sound

I am running Gnome 3.2 on Ubuntu 11.10.

In Banshee, I have 'Show Banshee in Sound menu' enabled in Edit-Preferences.

MPRIS D-Bus Integration and Sound Menu Integration extensions are also enabled.

Still, there is no Banshee on the sound menu.

What is missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Banshee's Sound Menu extension is specifically for [Ubuntu's sound menu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu).

Banshee doesn't currently make use of the playback controls in Gnome Shell's message tray and notifications.  That feature is [Bug 645628](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645628) if you're interested in following the progress.

However, as [Gamx points out below](https://askubuntu.com/a/74390/2079), even if this isn't possible out-of-the-box with Banshee, there are third-party solutions.

Webupd8's PPA provides a `gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer` extension that allows you to control various media players -- including Banshee -- using the controls in Gnome Shell.  To learn more about Personal Package Archives, see [this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).  To install the Gnome-shell extension, in terminal type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer
```

Comment: Does not work in 17.10: "E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gnome3/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file."

Comment: @GlenPeterson this is a very old question/answer. You shouldn't need a special plugin or PPA anymore. I'm pretty sure Gnome tray integration was added to Banshee several years ago.

Comment: It's in the Notification Area in Ubuntu 17.10.  I just didn't know to click on the time/date to see it.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see. I haven't updated to 17.10 (and actually, it's been a few years since I've used Banshee). Good luck.

Comment: What are you using instead of Banshee?

Comment: I ended up moving my collection to Google Music, but sometimes I miss having a local app.

Answer (score 3):

I may have misunderstood your question, but in gnome-shell you can have something very similar to the Sound Menu in Unity. Simply install gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer. You can find instructions here

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/gnome-shell-mediaplayer-extension.html