# How to make Banshee show up in the sound menu / topicons?

Tags: 17.10, banshee, gnome-shell, indicator-sound

## Problem

Is there even a "sound menu" anymore in 17.10?  When I have a lot of windows open and I get a phone call, I'm in the habit of stopping playback from the top bar somewhere near the sound icon.  Is there a way to do that, or something like it on 17.10?

## Failed Solutions

Under Edit -> Preferences -> Extensions, I tried both the "Notification Area Icon" and the "Sound Menu Integration" and don't see that these have any effect whatsoever.

I tried this: [I can not control Banshee from the sound menu in Gnome 3 Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72438/i-can-not-control-banshee-from-the-sound-menu-in-gnome-3-shell)
But when I issue `sudo apt-get update` I get:

```
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gnome3/ubuntu artful Release                
  404  Not Found
...
Reading package lists... Done                                      
E: The repository
    'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gnome3/ubuntu artful Release'
    does not have a Release file.
```

I then found the [gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer project on github](https://github.com/JasonLG1979/gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer), but they only support Gnome shell up through 3.24 and Ubuntu through 16.04, so I opened [this issue](https://github.com/JasonLG1979/gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer/issues/434).

`gnome-shell-extension-appindicator is already the newest version (17.10.2).` so maybe I just don't know how to use it?

I had already installed the gnome-tweak-tool so I tried (but did not reboot yet):

- **Top Bar:**

  - **Application Menu:** on, but no change.
  - **Activities Overview Hot Corner:** on, but no change.
- **Extensions:** I turned "Ubuntu appindicators" on, but no change.

## Question

Alternatives?  Suggestions?  I couldn't see how to do this in Rhythmbox either.  Maybe "topicons" and "sound menu" are not the right search terms?

Comment: Is there a "Where'd my stuff go? / How do I do stuff now?" page for upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10?  It's a pretty big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're playing a media file, basic controls (pause/next/previous) appear in the calendar & notification tray which can be accessed by clicking on the time indicator at the top bar.

[image]
([screenshot source](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/Notifications))

You can use the pause button to pause the track currently playing.